# Do the cyberlimb bonuses stack?

Tags: stacking, genesys

Page 177 in the Genesys core rules are the cyberlimb rules.
It is stated that replacing a limb lets you increase your characteristic (Agility or Brawn) by +1, and that your strain is decreased (up to a maximum of -2 for replacing all your arms and legs).

Now what I'm wondering is: Do these cyberlimb-bonuses stack?

Thus if I replace both arms and take Brawn as the characteristic, does that increase Brawn by +2?
Or is it more so, that you choose once when you first get a replacement and that +1 to either brawn or agility stays forever regardless how many more replacement limbs you gain?